How to monitor memory RW on jail-broken IOS device?
I am currently learning reverse engineering on iOS jailbroken devices. I found that I need to monitor the read and write operations of a specific address (usually a property of a C++ object).
I know two methods, but neither works well for my use case:

Frida’s MemoryAccessMonitor.enable: While it works, it monitors the entire memory page, and once it detects an access, it automatically disables the monitor. Re-enabling it frequently causes the app to crash.

LLDB: Although it can work, many system processes cannot be attached.


Is there a more universal way to achieve this?

The short answer is no; those ARE the universal ways.
